# RegExp for detecting single character not following by the same characters

Tags: regex

I am working at code editor and I need to create a cursor. It's just a simpe `|` symbol. But as you aknowledged `||` means `OR` in JavaScript. So I need regular expression to find single symbol `|` not surrounded by the another `|` symbol which means `OR`. I've tried something like `/^\|{1}$/igm` but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

**regex:** `(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)`

This uses negative lookahead and negative lookbehind to assert `|` is not preceded or followed by another `|`.

https://regex101.com/r/osE9Xx/1